# Hotel Price Check Guarantee - Heyitscheaper.com?

Tags: budget, hotels, accommodation, price, booking.com

I often use booking.com to book hotels with free cancellation, sometimes I cancel and rebook at a cheaper price because the price gets lower closer to the date.

I found the site http://heyitscheaper.com that claims to check the price of my hotel periodically and send me an email if it gets cheaper. It doesn't ask for any credit card or address etc. but I'd still like to know if there are any risks involved that I'm missing as it seems like a good service otherwise?

UPDATE: So I didn't hear anything from them for a week, then they sent me an email that my hotel was cheaper so I just cancelled and re-booked at the cheaper price ( benefits of free cancellation !) So I ended up saving 30$ with no hidden fees as advertised - highly recommend this site.

Comment: Since you've already been participating in other stackexchange sites I will not go into the good/bad question.  As it stands you're soliciting opinion from the group.

Comment: More importantly, I am asking users if there are any hidden risks in using this site which I may not be aware of - which is not an opinion based question. If someone's used it and leaves their opinion along with the answer to my question, they're more than welcome

Comment: Which is going to put your question on hold.  These discussions are reserved for chat.

Comment: I don't see why their should be any risk besides that someone collects data about you (Emailadress for spam connected to Locations where you obviously will go) - but collecting is an issue of every website so nothing really new

Comment: Thanks Gnusper, find it strange that with its current business model there doesn't seem to be any income for them. If they would have asked for credit card info, I'd have suspected credit card fraud for sure

Comment: Well if they inform you that it is cheaper and send you a link with it where you can book it, they will have income via link-directing. 
Also a lot of startups are just collecting "user" -> Facebook e.g. did (does?) not used to be profitable